# IDE - Add Custom Look and Feel to Intellij IDEA 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, look-and-feel

I'd like to use custom Look and Feel's for IntelliJ IDEA (for the IDE itself). I've tried adding the L&F **.jar** to the *libs* directory in the IDEA installation folder, as well as in my *{java_home}\libs\ext*, and specifying the Look and Feel in *{user}.IntelliJIdea11\config\options\options.xml*, under the `LAFManager` component, and it would only revert to the default ***Alloy: IDEA*** theme.

Can this be accomplished? Or can I add themes to the selection drop down in the IDEA Appearance settings panel?

Comment: Surely you have something more important to do?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I'm sure, but I just can't stand the default look and feels! None work well with dark editor themes.

Comment: May I ask why are you still using IntelliJ 11? IntelliJ 12 and higher has a beatiful dark L&F called Darcula out of the box

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt - The company I work for has not upgraded their licenses in some time. I've seen Darcula and it is rather pretty though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

1. Go into the "Color & Fonts" settings and tweak them to your liking. Of course, this really won't be a look & feel change. You can only tweak the editor panel and not the rest of the IDE.
2. Write a plug-in to add a new LAF. Keep in mind this is a lot of work. It took the JetBrains team a year to develop the Darcula L&F and that was with dedicated graphic artists to create a whole suite of icons and recommend color combinations. Since the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is open source, you could use that source code to develop your plug-in. I'm pretty sure Darcula is available in the community edition.

In the end, I think your best bet is to spring for a personal license of IDEA 14 if your company won't pay for an upgrade. At $99, that's about 40 cents a day for a year. Well worth it. And with the new subscription model, a license purchased now (good for 1 year of upgrades) will (most likely) be active when IntelliJ IDEA v15 is released assuming the typical late-November/early-December release time frame.