# How to get more Webstorm theme listed in Appearance

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, themes, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to change the look and feel of entire Webstorm editor. How can I add more themes in the Appearance section?
[image]

As of now it lists only 2 option, Default and Darcula.

Answer (score 10):

The 'Theme' dropdown in your snapshot actually refers to `Look & Feel` in the Intellij/Webstorm parlance. This is also seen if you try doing a `View -> Quick Switch Scheme` :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that the options in the above correspond to the 'Themes' dropdown in your snapshot.

I would imagine that creating a new Look&Feel would be a non-trivial task. This is somewhat substantiated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27864988/325742:

> Write a plug-in to add a new LAF. Keep in mind this is a lot of work.
> It took the JetBrains team a year to develop the Darcula L&F and that
> was with dedicated graphic artists to create a whole suite of icons
> and recommend color combinations. Since the IntelliJ IDEA Community
> Edition is open source, you could use that source code to develop your
> plug-in. I'm pretty sure Darcula is available in the community
> edition.

Therefore, you may not find a lot of stuff out there that change the whole Look and Feel of a Jetbrains product (like IntelliJ or WebStorm).

However, the best place to look for it would be in the plugins section.
Therefore:

#### First option: Theme Plugins

[image]

Note that, the complete appearance of Intellij changed when I installed this, however the plugins (I tried Material Theme UI) did not appear in the dropdown list.

#### Second Option : https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

This is just an editor color scheme and not a full fledged L&F plugin.

Download a color theme from there, then go to `File -> Import Settings` and choose the downloaded file after which you should see the following:

[image]

Finally, restart Webstorm:

[image]